# overflow hidden won't cut text

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have the following html and css

```
<div id="car-76" class="thumbnail_car thumbnail span2">
    <div class="thumbnail_creator">
        <hr>
        <div class="creator_img">
            <img alt="Bob Smith" height="40x40" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/df61dcc6eec08cb7d62f1959b89ae843?s=40&d=identicon&r=PG" width="40x40">
        </div>
        <div class="creator_details"> <a href="/users/2" title="John Malkovitchlongname the 3rd">
                       John Malkovitchlongname the 3rd
</a> 
        </div>
        <div class="creator_followers"> <a href="/users/2/followers"><i class=" icon-eye-open" title="Followers"> </i></a> 0</div>
        <div class="thumbnail_follow" id="follow_btn-2"> <a class="btn btn-primary" data-method="post" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">Follow</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the relevant css is

```
.thumbnail_creator .creator_details {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 77%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 44px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: clip;
}
```

I'd like long names to be cut if it reaches the end of the div, and not enter a new line

and for some reason doing `overflow: hidden` to hide the text and `text-overflow: clip` to clip the text won't do anything

so, instead of:

[image]

I want it to be (after editting the name to achieve the results)

[image]

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7NM2j/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

and setting some width on the content, since you have a fixed thumbnail width, this shouldn't be an issue, right?

see [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cdsSV/)

Hope it helps ^_^

**Update:**

- before I missed your fiddle, so I made the one for my demo. Here is a demo with your [**fiddle updated**](http://jsfiddle.net/7NM2j/5/). Here I also added allipsis to check out =)

Answer (score 0):

Also try and set the `max-width` css property of the .thumbnail_creator .creator_details divs.